# About piping stdio and subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, linux, shell, stdout, stdin

I have one Python program, that is opening another Python program via `subprocess.Popen`. The 1st is supposed to output some text into the console (just for info), and write some text to the 2nd program it had spawned. Then, it should wait for the 2nd program to respond (`read()` from it), and print that response.

The 2nd one is supposed to listen to the first one's input (via `raw_input()`) and then `print` text to the 1st.

To understand what exactly was happening, I had put a 5 second delay into the 2nd, and the result surprised me a bit.

Here's the code:

```
import subprocess

print "1st starting."

app = subprocess.Popen("name", shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) #<--- B

print "Writing something to app's STDIN..."
app.stdin.write(some_text)

print "Reading something from my STDIN..." #<--- A
result = app.stdout.read()

print "Result:"
print result
```

And for the 2nd one:

```
import time

print "app invoked."

print "Waiting for text from STDIN..."
text = raw_input()

#process(text)
time.sleep(5)

print "magic"
```

When I ran this code, it paused at point A, as that was the last console output.

After 5 seconds, the `"Result:\n"` line would be outputted, and everything the 2nd program had `print`ed would show up in the console.

Why did the 1st program pause when reading the stdout of the 2nd one? Does it have to wait for its child to terminate before reading its output? How can this be changed so I can pass messages between programs?

I'm running Debian Linux 7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies not in any magic related to the subprocess module, but in the typical behaviour of the `read()` method on Python objects.

If you run this:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
help(p.stdout.read)
```

You'll see this:

> read(...)
>
> ```
> read([size]) -> read at most size bytes, returned as a string.
>
> If the size argument is negative or omitted, read until EOF is reached.
> Notice that when in non-blocking mode, less data than what was requested
> may be returned, even if no size parameter was given.
> ```
>
> (END)

The same thing applies to all file-like objects. It's very simple: calling `read()` with no argument consumes the buffer until it encounters an error (usually EOF).

`EOF` is not sent until either:

- the subprocess calls sys.stdout.close(), or
- the subprocess exits and the Python runtime and/or OS kernel clean up its file descriptors

Beware that `os.read` has different behaviour - much more like typical buffered I/O in C. The built-in Python help function is useless, but if you're on any UNIXy system you should be able to run `man 3 read`; the Python behaviour more or less matches what's there.

### A word of warning

The program above is fine, but patterns like that sometimes lead to a deadlock. The docs for the subprocess module warns about this where Popen.wait() is documented:

> Warning
>
> This will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use communicate() to avoid that.

It's possible to get in a similar situation if you're not careful during two-way communication with a subprocess, depending on what the subprocess is doing.

**edit**:

By the way, [this page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) covers the behaviour of pipes with EOF:

> If all file descriptors referring to the write end of a pipe have been
>   closed, then an attempt to read(2) from the pipe will see end-of-file
>          (read(2) will return 0).

**edit 2**:

As Lennart mentined above, if you want truly two-way communication that goes beyond write-once read-once, you'll also need to beware of buffering. If you read [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects) you'll get some idea of it, but you should be aware that this is how buffered IO almost always works in UNIX-based systems - it's not a Python quirk. Run `man stdio.h` for more information.

Comment: I'll check out communicate, then, hopefully that will work as I want it. Thanks for that piping info, I'll definitely read it.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking program 1 to read input from program 2. And you are pausing program two for five seconds before it outputs anything. Obviously program 1 then needs to wait those five seconds. So what happens is perfectly expected.

> Does it have to wait for its child to terminate before reading its output?

To some extent, yes, because input and output is buffered, so it's possible that even if you move the delay to *after* you print something the same will happen.

`raw_input()` will wait for a linefeed, in any case.

Comment: I don't quite understand. I've already outputted 2 lines in the 2nd program before pausing it... But that remark about buffering is a bit scary...

Comment: My answer covers this behaviour 'in the large', but this answer is still relevant if you were to move to calling readline() or read(nbytes) - Python STDIN and STDOUT are buffered by default, and not flushed until you call flush() or the file descriptor is closed (usually when the program exists).

Comment: @Yannbane: Yeah, but those first two lines are sent before you wait for input from the first program! I don't understand what you expect to happen, so I don't know how to adjust tour expectations.

Comment: Thanks for all the info, but I ended up using temporary files instead.